# Memory retained by Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I call the `popBackStack` like:

```
manager.popBackStack("mybackstack", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

will the memory retained by the fragments that belongs to "mybackstack" will be freed?

I have a `FragmentActivity` that manages a `ListFragment`. Every time I click on item, the `FragmentActivity` instantiates a new `Fragment` which shows some information about the item clicked and then shows a `DialogFragment` with a Bitmap (that I recycle when the dialog is dismissed). I put the `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the manifest and override `onConfigurationChanged` as necessary.

Comment: I read somewhere that the developers site had failed to mention this information in the `FragmentManager` documentation and that it had only recently gotten updated. This might be why your question has gone so long without being answered :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the memory retained by the fragments will be freed. From the documentation,

> [**public static final int POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE**](http://goo.gl/G19tL)
>
> Flag for *popBackStack(String, int)* and *popBackStack(int, int)*: 
>   If set, and the name or ID of a back stack
>   entry has been supplied, then all matching entries will be consumed
>   until one that doesn't match is found or the bottom of the stack is
>   reached. Otherwise, all entries up to but not including that entry
>   will be removed.

and,

> [**public abstract void popBackStack (String name, int flags)**](http://goo.gl/NWyR9)
>
> Pop the last fragment transition from the manager's fragment back stack.
>   If there is nothing to pop, false is returned. This function is
>   asynchronous -- it enqueues the request to pop, but the action will
>   not be performed until the application returns to its event loop.

Note, however, that there is no guarantee that this memory will be freed immediately.